# QT GUI make for QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, plugins, pyqt, gui

I was used to develop qgis2leaf on a Ubuntu machine and after each change on the PyQT dialog I've used "make" in the terminal to "compile" the GUI.
How does this work on a Windows machine?

Comment: If you installed QGIS with OSGeo4W, you will have also a OSGEO Shell, that is a normale cmd.exe with all OSGEO path and env correctly configured. Opening the OSGEO shell, go to dir of you plugin and type make! make command should be installed with pyuic and pyrcc compilers

Comment: tried! got the response: make: pyuic4: Command not found.

Comment: the pyuic4 command is shipped with the qt installation according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429452/convert-pyqt-ui-to-python

Comment: hmmm... how did you installed QGIS with osgeo4w? it should install all this staff as "dependencies"... pyuic4 should belogs to PyQT4 package. Is it installed in your OSGeo4W environment?

Comment: No, I used the standalone installer. Yet this has the osgeo shell as well but "make" was not working. I now work on Ubuntu in a VirtualBox. So I am not dependend on an answer anymore but thanks!

Comment: I don't know if standalone installer installa al dev packages... osgeo4w installed does! use it, it's really more flexible at the momento to add new packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran in the same problem with the current QGIS 2.6.1 by just typing make I had the same error again.Now I've searched for the pyuic4.bat file and it was located correctly. SO I just used the absolute path in the OSGEO4W Shell:

```
C:\Users\ricckli\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgis2leaf>make
pyuic4 -o ui_qgis2leaf.py ui_qgis2leaf.ui
make: pyuic4: Command not found
make: *** [ui_qgis2leaf.py] Error 127
```

This one was working without a problem:

```
C:\Users\ricckli\.qgis2\python\plugins\qgis2leaf>C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\pyuic4 -o ui_q
gis2leaf.py ui_qgis2leaf.ui
```